# Are the right and bottom edges of a RECT structure treated as exclusive in all Windows API functions?

Tags: c, winapi

The documentations for the `RECT` structure says the following:

> By convention, the right and bottom edges of the rectangle are
>   normally considered exclusive. In other words, the pixel whose
>   coordinates are ( right, bottom ) lies immediately outside of the
>   rectangle. For example, when RECT is passed to the FillRect function,
>   the rectangle is filled up to, but not including, the right column and
>   bottom row of pixels.

Does that means that all Windows API functions treat the right and bottom edges of a `RECT` structure as exclusive, or should each function mention this explicitly?

I am asking because I have found two functions that uses a `RECT` structure, (`FillRect()` and `AdjustWindowRect()`), `FillRect()` mention this explicitly:

> When filling the specified rectangle, FillRect does not include the
>   rectangle's right and bottom sides. GDI fills a rectangle up to, but
>   not including, the right column and bottom row, regardless of the
>   current mapping mode.

While `AdjustWindowRect()` does not mention anything.

Comment: It should be safe to assume that they are exclusive *unless otherwise stated*.

Comment: [This article and Harry Johnston's comment above](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/18/75652.aspx) should answer your questions about RECT endpoints. I personally can't name a function that includes the point at `.right`/`.bottom`; `AdjustWindowRect()` does not.

Answer (score -2):

that is obvious because rect_width=(rect.right-(rect.left+1)) and idem with rect_height.

the same thing with arrays arr[5]; is in fact an array that start from 0 up to 4 but not 5;

Comment: ...no, rect_width = rect.right - rect.left; not + 1. This is the pattern I've seen used everywhere, on MSDN, on The Old New Thing, in sample code, etc. In faact there's [an article about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/18/75652.aspx) on The Old New Thing!